# Evitar que REG DELETE o REG ADD muestre confirmación en .bat

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, windows10, vbs

Estoy realizando una aplicación que pueda mandar información constante a un servidor y este, le pueda mandar ejecuciones de comandos ( **.bat** )a los clientes conectados.

Mi punto es que al momento de la ejecución del comando, muestra el **CMD**. Esto es un poco de lo que hago en el comando.

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f

REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /V WallpaperStyle /T REG_SZ /F /D 3
```

Intente con el script que se utiliza como intermediario (**.vbs**)

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Dim strArgs
strArgs = "cmd /c test.bat"
WshShell.Run strArgs, 0, true
```

[image: Resultado de la ejecución]
También adjuntare la pantalla de lo que se esta imprimiendo (tendrá `pause` , pero no, no es eso)

De antemano, muchísimas gracias.